# div tags width expands when more content is added

Tags: html, css, width

I am making a simple website for a friend. He needs to regularly add images to it yet he has no coding knowledge. My idea was to make the div that displays his images (horizontally as he requested) expand so all he has to do is add more images in the code and upload via filezilla.

I am having trouble making the div react to the content within it.  Here is the code:

```
#images {
    width:5000px;
    height:500px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:250px;
    margin-top:-80px;
}
#images img {
    height:500px;
}
```

This works but means that the width of the div has to be changed each time new content is added, I need it to grow with the content.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the width property from the div? Can you provide a JSFiddle so we can see all pieces?

Comment: if you keep on adding images horizontally it will introduce browser's horizontal scroll bar which is not recommended as per modern web standard

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2ofuuf2f/#&togetherjs=zdtFnNdG63) not sure if this is right @Goose, first time posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your container class to include `white-space:nowrap;` and you can remove the width too.

```
 #images {
   height: 500px;
   display: inline-block;
   white-space:nowrap;
   margin-left: 250px;
   margin-top: -80px;
 }
```

As mentioned above, scrolling horizontally isn't recommended. You can float items left as well but that will only affect the viewport of the browser.